# How can I bind a keyboard shortcut for npm script debug in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, hotkeys, vscode-keybinding

This code for configure test script to debug.

```
 {
  "name": "testproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "desc",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha test.js",
    "test_unit": "mocha test_unit.js"
  },
}
```

This is a screenshot of VS Code with Bug Button which starts the  test debug. It shows when I move mouse on it.

[image: Bug Button]

How I can set a hotkey on this button?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so? The relevant commands would be `npm.debugScript`, but the implementation of both those commands don't seem to be designed for use with keybindings. You can see the source code in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/078b98804ecf81cc7347a40604f63f4a494c9a71/extensions/npm/src/npmView.ts#L145. The furthest I can get in that direction is something like

```json
{
    "key": "", // TODO
    "command": "npm.debugScript",
    "args": {
        "script": {
            "packageJson": { "path": ".../package.json" },
        },
        "task": { "definition": { "script": "build" } }, // TODO: replace "build" with the script you want to run
        "package": { "resourceUri": { "fsPath": ".../package.json" } },
    },
},
```

And at that point you'll run into "`<minified variable name>.getFolder` is not a function".

If you want keybinding support for this command, you'll probably have to [raise a feature-request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md) or raise a PR.

---

You can, however, at least bind *running* (not debugging) the task to a keyboard shortcut:

```json
{
    "key": "", // TODO
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": {
        "task": "npm: build" // TODO: replace "build" with the name of the script you want to run
    },
},
```

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/202407